# How can I commit and add only one folder among many folder present there?

Tags: git, github, repository, commit

[The image here shows the multiple folder but I only want to commit only one folder "New Folder" which have files in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcd3Y.png)
[After committing and adding I want the following result not the same name but as a folder in repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeFb4.png)
I tried :

```
git commit prac -m "only-folder"
```

error: pathspec 'folder-name' did not match any file(s) known to git
But it gives the above error.
I only want to commit one folder and then add and upload it to my github 
 repository
as a folder only not as scattered files. 

 Please help me out here. 
 Thank You

[This is the Error I am getting. This is all I am doing. I want Example folder to be on github like in Picture2. Please help me out here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx2E8.png)

Comment: Please add more details. What error are you getting?

Comment: Add the folder to the staging area : `git add folder-name` and commit the changes `git commit -m "message"`, provided you have not done `git add .` previously and the folder  `folder-name` is not empty

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari I have not git add . previously. This will be my first time and yes other folder do contain files too

Comment: Please do tell me what should I do

Comment: @RemusCase `git add folder-name` and `git commit -m "message"` and then push it to Github, but before that you need to check the output of `git status` to make sure that `folder-name` was the only folder being staged for commit

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari , When I do ```git add folder-name```, it gives me fatal: adding files failed and error folder-name does not have commit checked out. How can I change the staging area to only that folder. Though ```git status``` gives me , Untracked files and all the folder names below.

Comment: @RemusCase You should update the question with the output of the same

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari  ,  Please do look into the question I have provided another screenshot at the end, which shows what I am trying to do. And the error it shows.

Comment: @ShreyaMalviya , I have tried to give all the details. Please do look into it. Thank You.

Comment: @RemusCase See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56873278/10155936)