# Having trouble with heroku and git for my discord bot

Tags: git, heroku

So I'm following this tutorial: https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/discord-py/hosting-a-discord-bot-for-free/ and I was getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyPythonFolder/Discord/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyPythonFolder/Discord/.idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: 'MyPythonFolder/Discord/among-us-bot1234/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

after I ran the code:

```
git add .
```

Here is my full cmd:

```
C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/cli/browser/fa74f932-feb1-48cc-af29-1ab8f995ff9f?requestor=SFMyNTY.g2gDbQAAAAw2OC4xOTYuODMuOTVuBgC2ut1PdgFiAAFRgA.KdgYZdPy5IkEVNVbkS1q23B2LkB-Jo93XT9vBCojPvs
Logging in... done
Logged in as pytthon.joshua@gmail.com

C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>heroku git:clone -a among-us-bot1234
fatal: destination path 'among-us-bot1234' already exists and is not an empty directory.

C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>heroku git:clone -a among-us-bot1234
Cloning into 'among-us-bot1234'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyPythonFolder/Discord/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyPythonFolder/Discord/.idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: 'MyPythonFolder/Discord/among-us-bot1234/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your errors one by one:

```
C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>heroku git:clone -a among-us-bot1234
fatal: destination path 'among-us-bot1234' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

you are cloning in a directory which is not empty. This is a bad idea: clone your repository into a new, empty folder. Git won't let you clone in that directory anyway.

```
C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>heroku git:clone -a among-us-bot1234
Cloning into 'among-us-bot1234'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

I assume you deleted your folder `among-us-bot1234` and cloned into it. Now that the folder *is* empty, the clone will be completed successfully. However, the remote repository is empty: there are no files in it.

```
C:\Users\Joshua\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord>git add .
[...]
error: 'MyPythonFolder/Discord/among-us-bot1234/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

Let us ignore the warnings on line ending for a minute, they are irrelevant. The  [does not have a commit checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873278/how-to-fix-error-filename-does-not-have-a-commit-checked-out-fatal-adding) is extensively discussed in this other question. The gist of it is: do not clone in a not-empy folder. If, for instance, you end up with nested `.git` folders, that is to say with nested local git repositories, this error might occour.

Go back to the tutorial, follow it, but clone into a local folder that is empty. Git will create the folder for you if it doesn't exists. Your local folder needn't share the same name as the repository.

**do you have nested git repositories?** Yes you do. `C:\Users\<yourname>\OneDrive\VscodePrograms\MyPythonFolder\Discord` *appears to be* a git repository (root or subfolder of one). You cloned something *inside* it in `[...]\Discord\among-us-bot1234`. You now have multiple nested git repositories, and that is to be managed. In your case, by not cloning inside an existing repository.

Comment: thanks, but now i have another error so ill make another question regarding it