# <file name> does not have a commit checked out

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to add my project to GitHub, I'm getting this error while using `git add .` command. Can someone please explain how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This indicates that you are using one or more submodules, and have not set up the submodule(s) yet. Do you intend to use submodules? If so, set them up.

Comment: Is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873278/how-to-fix-error-filename-does-not-have-a-commit-checked-out-fatal-adding/58530721) helpful?