Why can't I push my code into the existing repository?
I cannot push changes onto GitHub. I tried to push the same code into a new repository but I think I messed something up here...
That is the error-message I get:
PS C:\Users\tobia\chat-app> git add .


error: 'chat/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed

That is the link to my GitHub:
https://github.com/tostrauss/chat-app
The application compiles... it's just the pushing into GitHub that doesn't work!
I tried to create a new repository and even making a new GitHub account, also copying the codespace but nothing worked...

do you have ".git" folder in the root of your project?

I should yeah: git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/tobia/chat-app/.git/

Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873278/how-to-fix-error-filename-does-not-have-a-commit-checked-out-fatal-adding
